# Python. Ошибка: Большоe количества знаков после запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо вычислить арктангенс с одним очень большим (относительно другого) катетом.
Выдается ошибка

> OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

Как сделать чтоб ответ округлялся до заданного кол-ва знаков после запятой и таким образом обойти эту ошибку?

```
from math import atan
Катет1 = 10**1000
Катет2 = 10
alpha1 = atan(Катет1/Катет2)
print(alpha1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from math import atan
from decimal import Decimal

cat1 = Decimal(10**1000)
cat2 = Decimal(10)

alpha1 = atan(cat1 / cat2)
print(alpha1)
```

Вы можете обойти переполнения с помощью Decimal. И округление не понадобится

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import atan
Катет1 = 10**1000
Катет2 = 10
alpha1 = round(atan(Катет1/Катет2), [кол-во знаков после запятой])
print(alpha1)
```

Как вы поняли `round(x, n)` округляет `x` до заданного `n` знаков после запятой.
Данный метод не исправляет ошибку, исправить ее округляя нельзя, у python есть определенный размер ограничения чисел после плавающей точки, решается только `n // n2` который делит число нацело.

Comment: // тоже не поможет, а вот decimal - да. Сначала импортируем from decimal import Decimal, а потом пишем Decimal(10**1000) и Decimal(10)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант решения с помощью библиотеки `Numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

cat1 = np.float128(10**1000)
cat2 = 10

alpha1 = np.arctan(cat1 / cat2)
print(alpha1)
```

Вывод:

```
1.5707963267948966193
```